# how to select customer having relations of only one condition

Tags: sql, select

I have dbo.Customers and dbo.CustomerRelations tables.

dbo.Customers:

CustomerId, CustomerType

dbo.CustomerRelations:

MainCustomerId, RelatedCustomerId

for example main customers have many RelatedCustomers of different types:

| MainCustomerId | RelatedCustomerId | RelatedCustomerType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 111 | 1 |
| 55 | 112 | 1 |
| 55 | 113 | 4 |
| 55 | 114 | 3 |
| 55 | 115 | 3 |
| 55 | 116 | 1 |
| 66 | 661 | 1 |
| 66 | 662 | 1 |
| 77 | 771 | 1 |
| 77 | 772 | 3 |
| 88 | 881 | 1 |
| 88 | 882 | 1 |
| 88 | 883 | 1 |

In result, I want to get main customers, to whom are related only customers, having customer type for example 1. According to my example given above, i want to write a query that will give me customers:
88 and 66, who have only that related customers, who have type 1.
I don't want to get other main customers, that have relations of different customer types including type 1, but i want to get only that main customers, who have only that relations having type 1.

thank you.

Comment: Please tag the rdbms you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MainCustomerId
FROM mytable
GROUP BY MainCustomerId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN RelatedCustomerType = 1 THEN 1 END) >= 1
       and COUNT(CASE WHEN RelatedCustomerType <> 1 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

We need to select customers validating two conditions :

1. Having records with type 1 : `COUNT(CASE WHEN RelatedCustomerType = 1 THEN 1 END) >= 1`
2. Do not having any other type different than **1** : `COUNT(CASE WHEN RelatedCustomerType <> 1 THEN 1 END) = 0`

Comment: Thank you so much, it was really helpful answer. I got what I wanted in my sql query result.